# Web Services Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, https, wsdl

In my country, the goverment implemented a new form for paying taxes. We must use web services for comunication. The first part is to send a xml and after that I need to use a web service to know if the xml documento was accepted or not.
I am trying to invoke a web service from Netbeans. 
I have the url (https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/AutorizacionComprobantes?wsdl), the web method (autorizacionComprobante) and the parameter that I need for that method, for this particular example I am trying to get an xml object.

```
autorizacion.AutorizacionComprobantesService auService = new autorizacion.AutorizacionComprobantesService();
autorizacion.AutorizacionComprobantes comp = auService.getAutorizacionComprobantesPort();    
autorizacion.RespuestaComprobante resp = comp.autorizacionComprobante("2803201401179143437400110010010000000031234567818");        
List<autorizacion.Autorizacion> lista = resp.getAutorizaciones().getAutorizacion();
System.out.println(lista.size());
```

In this case I am printing the list size but I have no elements in that list which is totally incorrect. At least I should have 1 element but that list came completly empty.
I dont know what I am doing it wrong.
If someone know to solve this, I would be really thankful

Comment: Hmm, Cool government, well dear you have to contact the target developers, they will help you definitely.

Comment: cool spanglish code :trollface:

Comment: unfortunately they refused to help in software issues (according to them, they are always right and dont make mistakes jeje)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any sub elements under autorizaciones?
you cannot use resp.getAutorizaciones().getAutorizacion();

try

List lista = resp.getAutorizaciones();